# selecting a property from an object using Sequences in F#

Tags: xml, linq, xpath, f#

I am learning F# and have come across a question for which googling around did not help me much.

I have an Xml document with XmlNodes which are selected using Xpath. I have filtered the attributes and the attribute collection is able to be returned from the Seq. However, when i return the attribute value instead of the attribute, the following error is shown during compiling

`This expression was expected to have type
    'a option

but here has type
    string`

The Code snippet is given below

```
let doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument() in
                    doc.LoadXml xml;
                    doc.SelectNodes "//*[local-name()='SingleSignOnService']"
                        |> Seq.cast<System.Xml.XmlNode>
                        |> Seq.collect (fun node -> node.Attributes |> Seq.cast<System.Xml.XmlAttribute>)
                        |> Seq.filter (fun attr -> attr.Name.Equals("Binding",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        |> Seq.choose(fun attr -> attr.Value)
```

Please suggest me the right approach.

**EDIT**

Here is the solution that I formed with the help from Mr.Marklam. Hope this will help anyone else

```
let doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument() in
                    doc.LoadXml xml;
                    doc.SelectNodes "//*[local-name()='SingleSignOnService']"
                        |> Seq.cast<System.Xml.XmlNode>
                        |> Seq.collect (fun node -> node.Attributes |> Seq.cast<System.Xml.XmlAttribute> |> Seq.filter (fun attr -> attr.Name.Equals("Binding",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                        |> Seq.choose (fun attr -> if (attr.Name.Equals("Binding",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) then Some attr.Value else None)
```

Comment: Have you tried `Seq.map` instead of `Seq.choose`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to use `Seq.choose` to remove any `null` attribute values, you should convert the `attr.Value` to a `string option`.

The easiest way to do that is to pipe through `Option.ofObj`, i.e.

```
|> Seq.filter (fun attr -> attr.Name.Equals("Binding",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
|> Seq.choose(fun attr -> attr.Value |> Option.ofObj)
```

But if you know that the value is never null, you could use

```
|> Seq.choose (fun attr -> if attr.Name.Equals("Binding",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) then Some attr.Value else None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One small help, is the `Option.ofObj` available in F# for Visual Studio 2013, as I am not able to find it out. Also, please add a `(` after the if keyword in Seq.choose as that is not having a matching start parenthesis. Also, kindly suggest a good book for me to learn F# well.

Comment: ``Option.ofObj`` is in F#4, which doesn't seem to be available in 2013. You could define your own as ``let ofObj x = if x = null then None else Some x
``

Answer (score 3):

I gather there's some confusion with Linq extension methods.

`map(fun attr -> attr.Value)` is `Select(attr => attr.Value)`

`choose` is just `Where(option => option.HasValue).Select(option => option.Value)`

Here're a few more equivalents in C#/Linq

`collect` is `SelectMany`

`find` is `First`

`fold` is `Aggregate`

`singleton` is `Enumerable.Return`

Comment: `choose` is not equivalent to `Where`.  There is no LINQ equivalent to `choose` as it does not ordinarily make use of option types.  In F# `filter` is equivalent to `Where`.  `choose` could be thought of as a combined `map` and `filter` where the `None` values are filtered out and `Some x` becomes `f x`.

Comment: @TheInnerLight Good catch. Edited.

Comment: Thank you for the comparison between C# and its F# equivalents, I will have this in my F# notes. As mentioned in the previous response, please do share good F# book for my learning.